# LDAP Date Search Filter

Tags: java, ldap

Have to filter records on the basis of timestamp in LDAP . The Format used for the time stamp is 2"/28/2013 10:37:11 PM. Trying to put filter within LDAP but it does not work .What is use is "modifyTimestamp = *2/28/2013*" . Does any body know how to use it correctly

Comment: Can we see what you tried and what didn't work about it?

Comment: Within the search filter i gave "modifyTimestamp = *2/28/2013*" it searches for the records , bit no results . As the record exists or the same time stamp.

Comment: Perhaps it is looking for timestamps to be formatted like this "YYYYMMDDHHMMSSZ" (UTC)?

Comment: For some diff time format i.e 20-Jun-2013 i made a format as *20-JUN-2013* used this date in between of special character as (*) and it worked .

Comment: Which LDAP Directory Server are you talking too?  In general, the answer by Terry Gardner is the correct one.  Perhaps your server has an exception case?

Answer (score 1):

`modifyTimestamp` has generalized time syntax. When used in an assertion, the value must use that syntax, for example, `(modifyTimestamp=20130905020304Z)`. The complete syntax may be found in [RFC4517](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4517.txt).